# What's causing this tearing between my cube faces?

Tags: opengl, opengl-3

[image]

It's a little bit hard to see, but it looks like there's black and white dots between those two faces. I suspect it's one of OpenGL's quality settings, but I don't know which. Or would it be the texture min/mag filter (I have them both set to linear)? Or do I need mipmapping to solve this problem? Not quite sure what I should be looking for.

---

Figured out how to do mimapping....but that seems to make the problem worse.

[image]

Here are some of my settings (it's in C#, but it's just a thin wrapper over the C API)

```
VSync = VSyncMode.On;

GL.Enable(EnableCap.DepthTest);
GL.DepthFunc(DepthFunction.Less);

GL.Enable(EnableCap.CullFace);
GL.CullFace(CullFaceMode.Back);
GL.FrontFace(FrontFaceDirection.Ccw);

GL.ClearColor(Color.MidnightBlue);
GL.Enable(EnableCap.Texture2D);

GL.Hint(HintTarget.PerspectiveCorrectionHint, HintMode.Nicest);


texture = new Texture(TextureTarget.Texture2D);
texture.LoadImage2D("checkers.jpg");

GL.GenerateMipmap(GenerateMipmapTarget.Texture2D);

Texture.SetParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureMinFilter.LinearMipmapLinear);
Texture.SetParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureMagFilter.Linear);
Texture.SetParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureWrapS, TextureWrapMode.ClampToEdge);
Texture.SetParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureWrapT, TextureWrapMode.ClampToEdge);

Texture.SelectActive(TextureUnit.Texture0);
```

---

I can't notice it with other textures:

[image]

So maybe I just won't worry about it... on to lighting we go!

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to set the texture wrapping:

```
glTexParameterf (target, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameterf (target, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

If it's currently set to repeat, you'll get the artifacts you're seeing.

Comment: I vaguely remember that setting from years ago now! It solved my problem then...but not this time :( http://i.imgur.com/IdPFw.png

Comment: How is the checkerboard drawn? Is it just a texture, or is it a fragment shader?

Comment: Also, are you culling back faces? Is it possible the back of the face on the back of the cube is showing through?

Comment: The checker pattern is a texture, and yes, I'm culling back faces. Let me know if you need me to post some code/what you need to see.